# how to change header text by C# code in Windows-Mobile DataGrid?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to change header text and column size -  by C# code in **Windows-Mobile** DataGrid ?

Answer (score 0):

Gali -

```
dataGridView1.Columns[index].HeaderText = "I Like This Column Header Better";
```

...where "index" is either the index of the column you wish to change (zero-based) or the string name of the column at present.  The quoted text at the end is your new desired value.

Comment: Oh sorry.  Are you using an underlying DataTable or adding to the grid directly?

Comment: i use this to fill the datagrid: dataGrid1.DataSource = Main.dsParts2.Tables[1].DefaultView;

Comment: If dsParts2 is a DataTable type, you should be able to do "Main.dsParts2.Tables[1].Columns[index].HeaderText"